# Create a post request on ruby, based on a php version

Tags: php, ruby, post

i was away from Ruby for a while...now, i need to recreate a php api connection (curl) on ruby, to add it to my rails app, but all im getting is a Net::HTTPMovedPermanently message

here is the original php version:

```
$url = "https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3/token";
       $uniqid = uniqid();
       $authorization_key = base64_encode($client_id.":".$client_secret);
       $code = "";

       $ch = curl_init();
       $options = array(

               

                       "WM_SVC.NAME: Walmart Marketplace",
                       "WM_QOS.CORRELATION_ID: $uniqid",
                       "Authorization: Basic $authorization_key",
                       "Accept: application/json",
                       "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
               ),
       );
       curl_setopt_array($ch,$options);
       $response = curl_exec($ch);
       $code = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
       curl_close($ch);

       if($code == 201 || $code == 200)
       {
           $token = json_decode($response,true);
           return $token['access_token'];
       } 
   }
```

And this is my Ruby version so far:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'base64'

client_id = "id"
client_secret = "secret"

url = "https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3/token/"
uniqid = "1234567890abc"

uri = URI(url)

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
request['WM_SVC.NAME'] = 'Walmart Marketplace'
request['WM_QOS.CORRELATION_ID'] = uniqid
request.basic_auth(client_id, client_secret)
request['Accept'] = 'application/json'
request['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'



http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host)
response = http.request(request)
puts response
```

What im missing?

Update...

i've changed some things based on curl-to-ruby web, and is at follows...now im getting a 400 error

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

client_id = "foo"
client_secret = "bar"

url = "https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3/token"
uniqid = "1234567890abc"

uri = URI.parse(url)
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
request["WM_SVC.NAME"] = "Walmart Marketplace"
request["WM_QOS.CORRELATION_ID"] = uniqid
request.basic_auth(client_id, client_secret)
request["Accept"] = "application/json"
request.content_type = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"


req_options = {
  use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
}

response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, req_options) do |http|
  http.request(request)
end

puts response.code
puts response.body
```

i created a new question to clear out whats working so far, and the missing fields comparing to php

Comment: I am surprised the cURL version works at all - because what is fed to `curl_setopt_array` there, are not valid cURL options names to begin with. Looks like all of those _should_ actually be passed as headers.

Comment: _“but all im getting is a Net::HTTPMovedPermanently message”_ - and what is the actual target URL of that redirect, what does the `Location` header contain?

Comment: is the same address as the URL, which now i believe i get why, i wasnt using https, so it was redirecting me to https... when i added the use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https" its stopped redirecting, but now giving me a 400 error, so the packet im sending is wrong... not sure why though

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the resource you are trying to access has been moved. The HTTPMovedPermanently reponse is a form of HTTPRedirection. Your code should make another request to the new location.

This is the example directly from the Net::HTTP documentation:

```
def fetch(uri_str, limit = 10)
  # You should choose a better exception.
  raise ArgumentError, 'too many HTTP redirects' if limit == 0

  response = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI(uri_str))

  case response
  when Net::HTTPSuccess then
    response
  when Net::HTTPRedirection then
    location = response['location']
    warn "redirected to #{location}"
    fetch(location, limit - 1)
  else
    response.value
  end
end
```

Comment: but the php version works without any redirects... so my guess is that something is not being called properly

Comment: Some libraries automatically follow redirects for you. Net::HTTP does not. I suggest you try to follow the example.

Comment: I looked at your PHP code a little bit more closely and see that you are using some curl based library to make the request. The command line version of Curl does not follow redirects by default but can be configured to do so. My guess is that the PHP curl library you're using configures curl to follow redirects.

Comment: no, it didnt work with the redirect function either... i believe there is something wrong in the ruby code itself

Comment: The response['location'] is the same url addresss redirected to https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3/token
https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3/token   so its taken some parameter wrong to redirect to the actual uri that we added